# Unit vectors in Minkowski spacetime as we switch frames

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, geometry

I'm reading up about the geometry of flat spacetime in the context of special relativity, and I have a minor confusion about the following statement (in bold):

> The figure shows timelike and spacelike unit vectors: each vector connects the origin with a unit hyperbola. **These are not all unit vectors in the same frame; each would be a unit vector in some IRF, however.**

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what this means. If my understanding is correct, then a unit vector in one IRF has to be a unit vector in all IRFs due to the Lorentz invariance of the norm. If each of these is a unit vector in **some** IRF, then each of these is a unit vector in **all** IRFs, and so all of these have to be unit vectors in all the frames. So I don't know why it's claimed that *these are not all unit vectors in the same frame*. (Even if I'm not considering other frames - only considering the one in the diagram - then all of these are unit vectors in that frame since they connect the origin to the unit hyperbola)

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely correct.  The author either had a moment of confusion or meant to say something other than what he appears to be saying.  (PS---if you're going to quote a source like this you should really tell us the identity of that source.)

Comment: @WillO : whoops! The source is Core Principles of Special and General Relativity by Luscombe - fantastic book despite a few confusing statements!